# ¿Cómo puedo validar la integridad de una llave foránea entre dos entidades alojadas en dos microservicios diferentes?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, nestjs, apollo

Actualmente estoy trabajando con Apollo federation, nestjs y prisma con graphl y requiero ayuda con una validación. Tengo las siguientes entidades:

## Bodegas está alojada en el servicio 1

@ObjectType()

@Directive('@key(fields: "bodega_id")')

export class Bodegas {
@Field((type) => ID)
bodega_id: number

```
@Field((type) => String)
codigo: string

@Field((type) => String)
nombre: string

@Field((type) => Number)
centroTrabajoId: number
```

}

## Centros de trabajo está alojada en el servicio 2

@ObjectType()

@Directive('@key(fields:"centroTrabajoId")')

export class CentroTrabajo {

```
@Field(() => Int)
centroTrabajoId: number;

@Field()
codigo: string;

@Field({ nullable: true })
nombre: string;
```

}

Todo el código se basa en la documentación de este enlace: https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/federation

Este enfoque permite una conexión entre los microservicios y así mostrar los datos de los centros de servicios asociados a las bodegas y visceversa. Ahora bien, todo esto funciona perfectamente, el problema se presenta cuando hago una mutation, ya que me permite registrar una bodega con un id(centroTrabajoId) de un centro de trabajo que no existe.

¿Hay alguna forma de controlar que sólo se permita la inserción de un id(centroTrabajoId) que se encuentre registrado?

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda que me puedan brindar.